# Send Label text as parameter to target action when UISwitch is changed

Tags: ios, ios7, uiswitch

I have a simple settings page that is a dynamic Tableview and allows a user to use a UISwitch to toggle preferences.  I want to perform an action when the user toggles the switch (edit their preferences), but I can't get the cell.textLabel.text to the target method.

I can get the switch control's tag, but that isn't helpful since the tableview will be dynamic, therefore I have no way to know that 0=Technology, 1=Devotions, 2=Financial, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily loop through the cells and then find the UISwitch object by it's tag, compare the object pointer, then you have both the correct switch and the correct UITableviewCell that it exists in.

```
for (UITableViewCell* cell in self.tableview.visibleCells) {
    UISwitch* sw = [cell viewWithTag:1];
    if (sw == triggeredSwitch) {
        // this is the correct cell
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass which owns the switch and handles the switch action method. When the action method fires, the cell has access to its own label text - but really it should have some better identifier (as a property) and use that instead.

How you get the information out of the cell is then up to you, but giving it a delegate or a target/action pair to pass the data onto is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Another job for associated objects!

Creating a UISwitch that remembers some associated object.. (could be the cell, the table data, the category, etc)

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char * SwitchData = "SwitchData" ;

...

    UISwitch * theSwitch ;
    id switchData = ...object to be associated to switch...
    objc_setAssociatedObject( theSwitch, SwitchCategory, switchData, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC ) ;
```

In your action method:

```
-(void)switchTapped:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch * switch = (UISwitch*)sender
    id switchData = objc_getAssociatedObject( theSwitch, SwitchData ) ;

    ... switchData has your associated object ...
```